# navigate to the old page say page1 after selecting a value from page2 in Angular

Tags: angular

Let us say we have two pages Page1 and Page2 in Angular. I will have some input fields on Page1 and one hyperlink to go to the Page2. On Page2 I have a list of values each with a click button. I want to send this value to the old page.
I am succeeding to send the value from Page2 to Page1 by router but then it opens a new instance of Page1 and not the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You can either have shared state in a `Injectable` service class, set that state before going back to page1, and use it once you've navigated to page1.

Another option is to navigate to page1 with query params in the url if the data you are sharing is simple enough to be serialized in the url as query params.

If this isn't helpful, can you please try sharing some code in your question?

Comment: "Another option is to navigate to page1 with query params in the url if the data you are sharing is simple enough to be serialized in the url as query params."---

In this case will the old page still have the earlier data filled in other input fields?

Comment: When you navigate to pages in Angular, new instances of the components are created.  The exception to that is if you navigate to a different route, but the same component is used at both routes, then it may use the same instance of the component.  But in your case, you aren't able to go back to the same instance of page1 component that you had before.  So you'll want to use your shared data (query params or service member) to re-populate the page1compnent as you had it before.  If the data is not there, don't fill it out.  If the data is there, fill it out